# ImageView clear animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation in my code.
But I want when I click Button my ImageView return to original place(reset animation)
I have a method for that.
My code is :

```
 private void returnToOriginalRotationState() {
    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration((long) 2*1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    animation.setFillEnabled(true);
    imgHeade.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

It works as well 

But

```
    animation.setDuration((long) 2*1000);
```

not working !!!

Answer (score 1):

try this for clear animation:

```
 imgHeade.clearAnimation();
```